# Why is window.onhashchange "not a function"?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a site that presents different information for mysite.com/#!/pizza and mysite.com/#!/jellybeans. It seems like the window.onhashchange event is just what I need to get the functionality I want.

The following line of code returns the error *window.onhashchange is not a function*:

```
window.onhashchange( function() { alert(location.hash) })
```

But this other line of code works perfectly:

```
window.onhashchange = function() { alert(location.hash) }
```

Why is this? In my experience, to get something to happen in JavaScript you shove a function into the () after an event. Is that a jQuery thing? I think there's something fundamental I don't understand, and I'd like to know it so I don't have to experiment my way through any similar problem in the future.

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html. *"Is that a jQuery thing?"* Yes. The equivalent for native DOM would be `addEventListener`. For all `on*` DOM properties, binding happens  through assignment.

Comment: If you haven't set a value on it yet, `window.onhashchange` is `null`. `null(expr)` is a `TypeError: null is not a function(…)`. If you have set a value on it previously, this style would attempt to invoke that previous value - not update it. The best pattern to achieve what you want is `window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () { alert(location.hash); });` (if you wanted to later remove the handler you need to have kept a reference to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the first line is a function call:

```
window.onhashchange( function() { alert(location.hash) })
```

... And the second one defines a function:

```
window.onhashchange = function() { alert(location.hash) }
```